# SwiftUI: can you have a menu item with a checkmark and shortcut?

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

I'm writing a macOS app using SwiftUI, specifically, I'm adding a menu to the menu bar. The menu should have a selectable item -- item can have an optional checkmark in front of it -- and a shortcut. I cannot get it to work. It seems like you can either have a shortcut assigned -- you place a Button in the menu and attach the shortcut to the Button.

```
Button(String("Test")) {}
  .keyboardShortcut("1")
```

Or, you can have the item to be selectable -- you place a Button() into a Picker and set up the selection binding and the Button tag correctly.

```
Picker(selection: $selection) {
  Button(String("Test 1")) {}
    .tag(1)
}.pickerStyle(.inline)
```

But, not both. As soon as you put a Button with the shortcut into a Picker, the shortcut disappears.

```
Picker(selection: $selection) {
  Button(String("Test")) {}
    .keyboardShortcut("1") // << ignored
    .tag(1)
}.pickerStyle(.inline)
```

Am I missing something here or is this a known bug in SwiftUI? macOS 13.4.1, deployment target 12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think keyboard shortcuts on a `Picker` is currently supported. See also these related posts for people with similar situations: [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/tccc66/adding_keyboard_shortcut_to_picker/), [2](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733551).

As the first post says, you can use a bunch of `Toggle`s instead, though you would have to handle updating the states of other toggles yourself, so that no two toggles are on at the same time.

Example:

```
struct ToggleState: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var isOn = false
    let id: Int
    let shortcut: KeyboardShortcut
}
```

```
@State var toggles = [
    ToggleState(isOn: true, id: 0, shortcut: .init("A")),
    ToggleState(id: 1, shortcut: .init("B")),
    ToggleState(id: 2, shortcut: .init("C")),
]

var body: some View {
    ForEach(Array(toggles.indices), id: \.self) { i in
        Toggle("\(toggles[i].id)", isOn: Binding(get: {
            toggles[i].isOn
        }, set: { _ in
            for j in toggles.indices {
                toggles[j].isOn = false
            }
            toggles[i].isOn = true
        }))
            .keyboardShortcut(toggles[i].shortcut)
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw the posts you referenced. I think I missed the Toggle reference. Thank you for pointing it out.